# SQL - Include Rows with 0 Aggregate Results

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to create daily productivity reports that follow a template so that no edits need be done when updating a spreadsheet.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @Start, 101), foo, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN bar BETWEEN @Start AND @End AND bar <> baz THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [bar],
        SUM(CASE WHEN baz BETWEEN @Start AND @End THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [baz]   
FROM table (NOLOCK)
WHERE
    bar BETWEEN @Start AND @End
    and foo IN ('x','y','z')
GROUP BY foo
```

Now if either `[bar]` or `[baz]` have an aggregate value of greater than 0, then a row shows up for that entry in `foo`. However, I'd like EVERY value of `foo` to have a row, even if both `[bar]` and `[baz]` contain a zero. Is this possible without explicitly listing every value of `foo` in its own conditional?

---

## Example:

If I have a table

```
-------------
|foo|bar|baz|
-------------
| x | 1 | 2 |
| x | 2 | 3 |
| y | 2 | 6 |
| y | 3 | 2 |
| z | 9 | 9 |
-------------
```

Where `@Start = 1` and `@End = 5`, I currently get the output

```
-------------
|foo|bar|baz|
-------------
| x | 2 | 2 |
| y | 2 | 1 |
-------------
```

But I would like to get

```
-------------
|foo|bar|baz|
-------------
| x | 2 | 2 |
| y | 2 | 1 |
| z | 0 | 0 |
-------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to use `left outer join`.  Here is a fairly easy way to implement it, assuming that the `foo` values exist somewhere in the table:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @Start, 101), f.foo, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN bar BETWEEN @Start AND @End AND bar <> baz THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [bar],
        SUM(CASE WHEN baz BETWEEN @Start AND @End THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [baz]   
FROM (select distinct foo
      from table
      where foo in ('x', 'y', 'z')
     ) f left outer join
     table t (NOLOCK)
     on t.foo = f.foo and t.bar BETWEEN @Start AND @End
GROUP BY f.foo;
```

If the values don't exist in the table, then you can construct them manually:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @Start, 101), f.foo, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN bar BETWEEN @Start AND @End AND bar <> baz THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [bar],
        SUM(CASE WHEN baz BETWEEN @Start AND @End THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [baz]   
FROM (select 'x' as foo union all select 'y' union all select 'z'
     ) f left outer join
     table t (NOLOCK)
     on t.foo = f.foo and t.bar BETWEEN @Start AND @End
GROUP BY f.foo;
```

Comment: I see the logic here and I like this approach, but it still isn't populating the rows that have 0s. :(

Comment: @Andy . . . Of course not.  The `where` clause was converting the `left join` to an inner join.  The solution is to put the condition in the `on` clause.

Comment: That did it beautifully. I need to read up on how to better use the `on` clause, I suppose.